# Error while initializing the structure values

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have just started using pointers.So please bear with me if this looks silly
But I am not able to find the reason.
I have a structure

```
typedef struct Intermediatenode
{
    int key;
    char *value;
    int height;
    struct node *next[SKIPLIST_MAX_HEIGHT];
} node;
```

And I wand to create a new node by using below function

```
 node *create_node(int key, char * val, int h)
 {
        node *newnode;
        newnode=malloc(sizeof(node));
        newnode->height=h;
        newnode->key=key;
        printf("till here %s \n",val);
        printf("till here %d \n",newnode->height);
        printf("till here %d \n",newnode->key);
        strcpy(newnode->value,val);
        printf("till here %s \n",newnode->value);
        return newnode;
 }
```

But I Am getting segmentation fault at this 
"strcpy(newnode->value,val);"
Can you please help me with that.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You allocated memory for the node, but not the string in `value`.  The `strcpy` function will copy bytes but not allocate memory.  It assumes that you've already arranged that.  In a pinch, you can allocate and copy the string with `strdup`:

```
newnode->value = strdup(val);
```

Comment: Note that when you `free` your node later, you'll need to first `free` that `value`.